# Why is adding keyword arguments in call to Python websocket function via Matlab throwing an error?

Tags: python, matlab, websocket

I need to translate the following code from Python to Matlab syntax.

Python code that works:

```
ws = websocket.create_connection("wss://echo.websocket.org", sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

Matlab translation attempt:

```
ws = py.websocket.create_connection('wss://echo.websocket.org/', pyargs('sslopt','{"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}'))
```

This Matlab line gives the following error:

> Error using _http>_ssl_socket (line 245) Python Error: ValueError:
>   dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
>
> Error in _http>connect (line 126)
>                   sock = _ssl_socket(sock, options.sslopt, hostname)
>
> Error in _core>connect (line 223)
>                                      options.pop('socket', None))
>
> Error in _core>create_connection (line 514)
>       websock.connect(url, **options)

Interestingly, not adding the keyword argument works, however it does not help me because I must skip SSL certificate verification:

```
ws = py.websocket.create_connection('wss://echo.websocket.org/')
```

I've tried adding url= or name= like in previous related threads to no avail:

```
ws = py.websocket.create_connection(py.list({'url','wss://echo.websocket.org/'}),pyargs('sslopt','{"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}'))
```

I suppose this is a syntax problem! A good idea would be really helpful, thank you!